# Small powers of small numbers: Is there really a pattern or am I just used to looking for them?

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion, perfect-powers

This probably is just a coincidence, but I've always found it interesting and I wanted to put some feelers out there to see if maybe there really is something to it after all.

There are these collections of powers, and in one case a sum of powers in two different ways, that have similar digits to each other.

$$3^7 = 2187$$
$$6^4 = 1296$$
$$12^3 = 1728$$
$$13^3 = 2197$$
$$1^3 + 12^3 = 9^3 + 10^3 = 1729$$
$$3^6 = 729$$

(I suppose the last two are inevitable in any radix.)

We also have

$$2^{10} = 1024$$
$$7^4 = 2401$$

and

$$2^8 = 256$$
$$5^4 = 625$$
$$24^2 = 576$$

I can see the following class is inevitable in any radix > 4.

$$12^2 = 144$$
$$21^2 = 441$$

$$13^2 = 169$$
$$31^2 = 961$$

Is there an overarching mechanism at play here, or am I just finding statistically insignificant patterns?

Comment: You mentioned some patterns. From which one do you want to know whether it holds for larger perfect powers. Is it that two perfect powers consist of the same digits , just in another order ?

Comment: The example with the two representations as a sum of two cubes is called "taxicab number"

Comment: @g.kov -- Oops, thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @Peter -- I'm not asking about existence at higher powers, I'm asking if there's an overarching mechanism at play.

Comment: See [OEIS A$128993$](http://oeis.org/A128993).

Comment: Benfords law predicts that most of the digits will be low numbers (about 60% of the digits will be 1,2,3), so given that fact, a combinatorical explanation might probably do it.

Comment: @KessemClein, was going to say just that, but had forgotten the name of the law.  Thanks.  [Here is the Wikipedia page for it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really only a tiny piece of an answer, but...

This is a very interesting question. My first reaction is to think that it can't be a coincidence, but I'm not certain.

Now, a statistical explanation seems more or less plausible. You're mostly looking at numbers up to $13$ raised to numbers up to $10$, so there are about $12 \cdot 9 = 108$ "interesting" powers. Meanwhile, there are $286$ ways of choosing $4$ digits, with duplicates allowed but disregarding order. So it shouldn't be too uncommon for powers to be anagrams.

Still, this "family" of prime powers seems pretty compelling:

$5^2 = 25 = 24 + 1$

$7^4 = 2401 = 24 \cdot 10^2 + 1$

$2^{10} = 1024 = 24 + 10^3$

We can examine the relationships between these equations a little more clearly by pairing them up, multiplying by $10^2$ as needed, and subtracting them to cancel the $24$s:

$2^2 \cdot 5^4 - 7^4 = 10^2 - 1$

$2^{10} - 5^2 = 10^3 - 1$

$2^{12} \cdot 5^2 - 7^4 = 10^5 - 1$

By coincidence or otherwise, all of the powers on the left-hand side are even, so we can apply the difference-of-squares formula. We can also factor the right-hand sides, of course. These equations factor as:

$(2 \cdot 5^2 - 7^2) (2 \cdot 5^2 + 7^2) = (10 - 1) (10 + 1)$

$(2^5 - 5) (2^5 + 5) = (10 - 1) (10^2 + 10 + 1)$

$(2^6 \cdot 5 - 7^2) (2^6 \cdot 5 + 7^2) = (10 - 1) (10^4 + 10^3 + 10^2 + 10 + 1)$

Then, if we replace each factor with its own prime factorization, we end up with:

$(1) (3^2 \cdot 11) = (3^2) (11)$

$(3^3) (37) = (3^2) (3 \cdot 37)$

$(271) (3^2 \cdot 41) = (3^2) (41 \cdot 271)$

But this definitely doesn't seem like a compelling explanation of anything. We started with some pretty interesting equations, like $2^{10} - 5^2 = 10^3 - 1$, and "explained" them by progressively factoring them, but there's no explanation of why the prime factors on the left ended up matching the prime factors on the right.